# Youtube api get subbed channels

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

is there something in the youtube api to get all channels where I do have a subscription? In general it means to return a list with the channels you can find under youtube.com/feed/channels.
I've looked in the api, but couldn't find. Seems there are only functions to return channels which subbed me, but I need the other way.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should check [activtes.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) the response contains subscriptions

[activities.resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities#resource)

```
 },
    "subscription": {
      "resourceId": {
        "kind": string,
        "channelId": string,
      }
    },
```

This may not be exactly what you are looking for but i think its as close as you will get.   I know of no other method that shows what subscriptions a user has.